# Best way (threads/event-driven) of fetching data from many web pages

Tags: python, ruby, multithreading, events, thread-safety

*I don't want to make holywar on any reason, just to get advice and continue development.*

I need to write something like crawler, 
it must be able to fetch some data from list of URLs and parse it.

I am going to use **Ruby** (*mechanize + nokogiri*) or **Python** (*mechanize + beautifulsoup*).

But I need to do parallel data handling for efficiency. That's a big problem for me now.

Mechanize (for both languages) is not thread safe as far as I know, also using threads is not "good practice" as many programmers says. From other side I have no idea about event-driven programming technics and how it can be used in my case.

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: From my experience mechanize is not flexible enough for every crawling need, so you may have to roll some of that yourself. Also I found lxml to be far more effective in the long run than BeautifulSoup, and faster, and more stable. Keep lxml on your list of possibilities.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've been using [Scrapy](http://scrapy.org/) with great success. It's quite straightforward and allows for multiple crawlers at once. Outputs to json, xml, etc or directly to a database. It's worth a look for sure.